# Reading comprehension: how many times did Lee blow into the device?

Tags: meaning-in-context

How many times did Lee blow into the device? Is it 5 or 8?
My English is not great, just need to figure out this report.

Thanks!

> At approximately 0427hrs LEE blew into the second ASD. LEE got three
>   consecutive 'NOGO' responses as she was not blowing
>   sufficiently/correctly into the device.
>
> PC ** HEAD used a new, unused clean AS mouth tube and showed her how to blow into an through the ASD mouth tube, and instructed her to
>   provide the sample again.
>
> LEE continued to not blow into the device when advised. LEE had no difficulty blowing on the first device and PC ** HEAD determined that
>   she was intentionally not blowing on the device.
>
> After five further 'NOGO' attempts PC ** HEAD stopped the ASD analysis opportunity and advised LEE that her first FAIL reading would
>   be the final/only result.

Comment: It is not said in this excerpt what the results of blowing on the first device were. LEE was given at least eight opportunities to blow into the second device, three with the original mouth tube and five with the new one; it appears that she did not blow into it at all, at least not with sufficient force to register.

Comment: Can you cite a web reference for the passage, to make further context available?

Answer (score 3):

I think the passage is not clear enough to tell for certain how many attempts were made.  It appears there were “three consecutive 'NOGO' responses” on “the second ASD”, followed by demonstration of use by a PC, and then “five further 'NOGO' attempts”.  In addition, apparently there were some NOGO attempts on a first ASD (the occurrence of NOGO attempts providing reason to try a second ASD) in addition to one or more FAIL readings  on a first ASD.  (Phrase  “first FAIL reading” suggests there were multiple FAIL readings; but “final/only result” suggests only one result was obtained.  I suppose that PASS and FAIL count as *results* and that NOGO counts as an attempt.

Summary: I think the answer to “How many times did Lee blew into the device?” is nine times or more.